# changing tabstop from 4 to 2 after using expandtab (with minimum manual effort)

Tags: vim, tabs, tabstop

For some time I have used tabstop=4 in my source files. Now that I write lot of javascript that has deep indentations, a tabstop of 4 seems wasteful, so I want to convert it to 2. The problem is I use "set expandtab" too. So merely setting tabstop=2, won't help.

Any suggestions on how I can convert all my files quickly to tabstop 2?

My current relevant .vimrc settings are

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do

```
" convert spaces to tabs first
set noexpandtab
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
retab!
" now you have tabs instead of spaces, so insert spaces according to
" your new preference
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
retab!
```

in a vim window, and it will retab according to your preferences.  You can probably create a mapping to make this easier, or record a macro.  There might be another way, but the above should work.  (`"` is comment)

Answer (score 6):

You can change your settings, select all, and hit the `=` key to indent it:

```
ggVG=
```

I also recommend using ftplugin to specify settings per file type.

Comment: I *knew* there was an easy way!

Comment: @Alok: You may want to leave your answer anyhow.  Looking at the VIM docs, it may be fundamentally different than applying indent.  I guess he should try both to find out.

Comment: Well, your method reindents everything, which is, as you said, different from preserving the intent of the indent already in the code.  Good point, I will undelete my answer.

Comment: I tried this, it does reduce the indentation, but it doesn't work quite right. I think it recalculates indents instead of only changing existing tabs.

Comment: @Jayesh: That's exactly what = does: reindent according to your settings; see :help =.